# Delay on drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

Well I have the following code that I am using for drawing on canvas. But the lines are getting polygons and delayed after first line. please help if anyone know 
This is my JS code and I am using EaselJS

```
    var app ={
    stage:null,
    stagetools:null,
    container:null,
    loader:null, 
    stageArea:null,
    backgroundContainer:null,
    backgroundBounds:null,
    oldPt:0,
    oldMidPt:0,
    midPt:0, 
    NUM_LINES: -1,
    manifest:[],
    toolsAssets:[],
    lineArray:[],
    lineArray2:[],
    lineArray3:[],
    filters:[],
    filters2:[],
    mouseDOWN:false,
    bgscale:null,


    init: function(chosenNum){


        //filters
        this.filters[0] = new createjs.Shadow('#0066cc',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[1] = new createjs.Shadow('#0ceaed',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[2] = new createjs.Shadow('#00ff2a',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[3] = new createjs.Shadow('#de00ff',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[4] = new createjs.Shadow('#f40045',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[5] = new createjs.Shadow('#d8ff00',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[6] = new createjs.Shadow('#ff8400',1, 1, 30);
        this.filters[7] = new createjs.Shadow('#7d36ff',1, 1, 30);


        this.filters2[0] = new createjs.Shadow('#0066cc',0, 0, 10);
        this.filters2[1] = new createjs.Shadow('#0ceaed',0, 0, 10);
        this.filters2[2] = new createjs.Shadow('#00ff2a',0, 0, 10);
        this.filters2[3] = new createjs.Shadow('#de00ff',0, 0, 10);
        this.filters2[4] = new createjs.Shadow('#f40045',0, 0, 30);
        this.filters2[5] = new createjs.Shadow('#d8ff00',0, 0, 30);
        this.filters2[6] = new createjs.Shadow('#ff8400',0, 0, 30);
        this.filters2[7] = new createjs.Shadow('#7d36ff',0, 0, 30);


        //setup
        this.stagetools = new createjs.Stage('canvasTools');
        this.stagetools.enableDOMEvents(true);
        this.stagetools.enableMouseOver(10);
        createjs.Touch.enable(this.stagetools);


        this.stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas'); 
        //this.stage.autoClear = true;
        this.stage.enableDOMEvents(true);
        this.stage.snapToPixelEnabled = true;
        this.stage.enableMouseOver(10);
        createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60); 
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.tick); 


        //loader
        this.manifest = [
            {src:'images/brush.png',    id:'brush',    link: 'tool'},   
            {src:'images/undo.png',     id:'undo',     link: 'tool'},
            {src:'images/clear.png',    id:'clear',    link: 'tool'}
        ];



        switch(chosenNum)
        {
            case 0: this.manifest.push({src:'images/boom.jpg',id:'fc0', link:'car'}); break;  
            case 1: this.manifest.push({src:'images/hellosunshine.jpg',id:'fc1', link:'car'}); break;    
            case 2: this.manifest.push({src:'images/iceicebaby.jpg',id:'fc2', link:'car'}); break;       
            case 3: this.manifest.push({src:'images/boom.jpg',id:'fc3', link:'car'}); break;   
            case 4: this.manifest.push({src:'images/hellosunshine.jpg',id:'fc4', link:'car'}); break;
            case 5: this.manifest.push({src:'images/iceicebaby.jpg',id:'fc5', link:'car'}); break;
            default: this.manifest.push({src:'images/hg10.jpg',id:'fc0', link:'car'}); break;  
        }


        this.loader = new createjs.LoadQueue();
        this.loader.on('complete', this.handleComplete);
        this.loader.on("fileload", this.handleFileLoad);
        this.loader.loadManifest(this.manifest);    



        //containers
        this.backgroundContainer = new createjs.Container();
        this.stage.addChild(this.backgroundContainer);

        var ss = new createjs.Shape();
        ss.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawRect(0, 0, 960, window.innerHeight);

        this.stageArea = new createjs.Container();
        this.stageArea.snapToPixel = true;
        this.stageArea.hitArea = ss;
        this.backgroundContainer.addChild(this.stageArea);    


        this.container = new createjs.Container();          
        this.stage.addChild(this.container);    


        this.stageArea.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
        this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove" , this.handleMouseMove);   


    },


    handleFileLoad:function(e){
        app.toolsAssets.push(e);    
    },

    handleComplete:function(){      
        tools.init();

        //background
        for(var i = 0; i < app.toolsAssets.length; i++){
            if(app.toolsAssets[i].item.link == "car"){
                var imgLoader = app.loader.getResult(app.toolsAssets[i].item.id);
                var img = new createjs.Bitmap(imgLoader);

                app.backgroundBounds = img.getBounds();
                app.backgroundContainer.addChild(img);
                img.cache(0,0, img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);
            }
        }


        resize();

    },

    handleMouseDown:function(){


        app.mouseDOWN = true;

        app.NUM_LINES++;

        var drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
        drawingCanvas.snapToPixel = true;
        //drawingCanvas.cache(0, 0, app.stage.width, app.stage.height);
        drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(tools.size, 'round', 'round');
        app.container.addChild(drawingCanvas);


        var drawingCanvas2 = new createjs.Shape();
        drawingCanvas2.snapToPixel = true;
        //drawingCanvas2.cache(0, 0, app.stage.width, app.stage.height);
        drawingCanvas2.graphics.setStrokeStyle(tools.size-2, 'round', 'round');
        app.container.addChild(drawingCanvas2);


        var drawingCanvas3 = new createjs.Shape();
        drawingCanvas3.snapToPixel = true;
        //drawingCanvas3.cache(0, 0, app.stage.width, app.stage.height);
        drawingCanvas3.graphics.setStrokeStyle(tools.size-3, 'round', 'round');
        app.container.addChild(drawingCanvas3);


        app.lineArray.push(drawingCanvas);
        app.lineArray2.push(drawingCanvas2);
        app.lineArray3.push(drawingCanvas3);

        tools.undoArray.push(drawingCanvas);
        tools.undoArray2.push(drawingCanvas2);
        tools.undoArray3.push(drawingCanvas3);

        tools.selectedArray.push(tools.SELECTED);


        app.oldPt = new createjs.Point(app.stage.mouseX - app.stage.canvas.width/2, app.stage.mouseY-app.stage.canvas.height/2);    
        app.oldMidPt = app.oldPt;

        app.stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove" , app.handleMouseMove); 


    }, 

    handleMouseMove:function(){



        app.stage.removeEventListener("stagemousemove" , app.handleMouseMove);  
        app.stageArea.addEventListener("pressup", app.handleMouseUp);           
    }, 

    handleMouseUp:function(){
        app.mouseDOWN = false;

        app.stageArea.addEventListener("mousedown", app.handleMouseDown);
        app.stageArea.removeEventListener("pressup", app.handleMouseUp);


        for(var i = 0; i < app.lineArray.length; i++){
            app.lineArray[i].shadow = app.filters[ tools.selectedArray[i] ];
            app.lineArray2[i].shadow = app.filters2[ tools.selectedArray[i] ];
            app.lineArray3[i].shadow = new createjs.Shadow('#ffffff',0, 0, 6);
        }

        app.stage.update();


    },

    tick:function(){

        if(app.mouseDOWN){

            app.midPt = new createjs.Point(app.oldPt.x + app.stage.mouseX - app.stage.canvas.width/2>>1, app.oldPt.y+app.stage.mouseY - app.stage.canvas.height/2>>1);


           app.lineArray[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.lineArray2[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.lineArray3[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.oldPt.x = app.stage.mouseX;
            app.oldPt.y = app.stage.mouseY;

            app.oldMidPt.x = app.midPt.x;
            app.oldMidPt.y = app.midPt.y;



            app.stage.update();
        }   



    }

}

var tools = {

    selectedArray:[],
    undoArray:[],
    undoArray2:[],
    undoArray3:[],
    palettes: ['#0066cc', '#0ceaed', '#00ff2a', '#de00ff', '#f40045', '#d8ff00','#ff8400','#7d36ff'],
    sizes:[6, 10, 15],
    colourPallette:null,
    paletteColours: null,
    brushSizes:null,
    toolsContainer:null,
    size: 8,
    toolsScale:1,
    COLOUR: '#0066cc',
    SELECTED:0,

    init:function(){



        //colour pallette
        this.toolsContainer = new createjs.Container();
        this.toolsContainer.x = app.stagetools.canvas.width/2 - 150;
        this.toolsContainer.y = app.stagetools.canvas.height/2 + 10;
        app.stagetools.addChild(this.toolsContainer);



        this.colourPallette = new createjs.Shape();
        this.colourPallette.name = 'colourPallette';
        this.colourPallette.graphics.beginFill(tools.COLOUR);
        this.colourPallette.graphics.setStrokeStyle(4, 'round').beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
        this.colourPallette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,22);
        this.colourPallette.addEventListener('click', this.palletteHandler);
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.colourPallette);


        this.paletteColours = new createjs.Container();
        this.paletteColours.visible = false;
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.paletteColours);

        for(var i = 0; i < this.palettes.length; i++){
            var palette = new createjs.Shape();
            palette.name = 'palette' + i;
            palette.graphics.beginFill(this.palettes[i]);
            palette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,15);
            palette.addEventListener('click', this.palletteHandler);
            palette.x = (i * 50);
            palette.y = -50;
            this.paletteColours.addChild(palette);
        }

        //brush tool
        var brush = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('brush'));
        brush.name = 'brush';
        brush.x = 50;
        brush.y = -34;
        brush.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(brush);    


        this.brushSizes = new createjs.Container();
        this.brushSizes.x = brush.x + 40;
        this.brushSizes.y = brush.y - 20;
        this.brushSizes.visible = false;
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.brushSizes);


        for(var p = 0; p < this.sizes.length; p++){
            var size = new createjs.Shape();
            size.name = 'size'+p;
            size.graphics.beginFill('#FFFFFF');
            size.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,this.sizes[p]);
            size.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);     
            size.x = (p==1) ? p * 40 : p * 45; 
            this.brushSizes.addChild(size);
        }


        //undo tool
        var undo = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('undo'));
        undo.name = 'undo';
        undo.x = brush.x + 90;
        undo.y = brush.y;
        undo.addEventListener('click', this.undoHandler); 
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(undo); 

        //trash tool
        var clear = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('clear'));
        clear.name = 'clear';
        clear.x = undo.x + 90;
        clear.y = undo.y;
        clear.addEventListener('click', this.clearHandler); 
        this.toolsContainer.addChild(clear);    

    },

    brushHandler:function(e){

        tools.paletteColours.visible = false;
        tools.brushSizes.visible = false;

        switch(e.target.name)
        {
             case 'size0': tools.size = 6; break;
             case 'size1': tools.size = 10; break;
             case 'size2': tools.size = 15; break;
             case 'brush': tools.brushSizes.visible = true; break;
        }

        app.stagetools.update();
    },

    palletteHandler:function(e){

        tools.paletteColours.visible = false;
        tools.brushSizes.visible = false;

        switch(e.target.name)
        {

         case 'colourPallette': tools.paletteColours.visible = true; break;

         case 'palette0':
                tools.SELECTED = 0;
                tools.COLOUR = '#0066cc';
                break;

         case 'palette1':
                tools.SELECTED = 1;
                tools.COLOUR = '#0ceaed';
                break;  

         case 'palette2':
                tools.SELECTED = 2;
                tools.COLOUR = '#00ff2a';
                break;      

         case 'palette3':
                tools.SELECTED = 3;
                tools.COLOUR = '#de00ff';
                break;

         case 'palette4':
                tools.SELECTED = 4;
                tools.COLOUR = '#f40045';
                break;  

         case 'palette5':
                tools.SELECTED = 5;
                tools.COLOUR = '#d8ff00';
                break;      

         case 'palette6':
                tools.SELECTED = 6;
                tools.COLOUR = '#ff8400';
                break;  

         case 'palette7':
                tools.SELECTED = 7;
                tools.COLOUR = '#7d36ff';
                break;                          
        }

        tools.colourPallette.graphics.beginFill(tools.COLOUR);
        tools.colourPallette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,22);

        app.stagetools.update();

    },

    undoHandler:function(){

        if(tools.undoArray.length){
            var lastItem = tools.undoArray.pop();
            app.container.removeChild(lastItem);        

            var lastItem2 = tools.undoArray2.pop();
            app.container.removeChild(lastItem2);

            var lastItem3 = tools.undoArray3.pop();
            app.container.removeChild(lastItem3);

            app.stage.update();
        }

    }, 

    clearHandler:function(){
        app.container.removeAllChildren();
        app.container.removeAllEventListeners();
        app.stage.update();
    },

}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to look through that much code.

Comment: I don't want to look through that code. I give all I have to identify the error. How you can see the whole code is commented so will be easy to pass what is not important

Comment: I'd suggest some console.log's on your init method etc as I aimagine they are bewing called more time then you intend. there are also lots of variable etc that get created on each event and they could be combined and reused.

Comment: I have used console.log and is no error there. Everything looks normal